# Let $A = \{1, 2, 3\}$ and $B = \{a, b\}$, which choice is false?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

1. $(1,1) \in A\times A$
2. $| A\times B | = | B\times A |$
3. $(a,2) \in B\times A$
4. $(1,2,3) = (2,1,3)$

These are the possible answers. I went through them all and they all seem to be true and I just cannot see which one is false. For the first one, I'm assuming that the set of $A$ squared must contain $(1,1)$ because the set has one in it. For the second, wouldn't the cardinality be the exact same because in the end both Cartesian products have six elements. For the third I figured that is the easiest one and for the last one, I do not think it matters the order as long as they have the same elements, correct? Thank you, any help is appreciated!

Comment: The order of the entries matters in an ordered tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Tuples, denoted $(x,y)$ are not sets, denoted $\{x,y\}$. Sets may be unordered, but tuples are ordered.

Examples: $\{1,2,3,4,5\} = \{5,2,1,3,4\}$. Both are the same sets, defined simply by the elements they contain, and no more.

On the other hand, for tuples, the order of elements within the tuple is definitive. Think of coordinates! When you write $(x,y)$, order obviously matters: on a grid, the point $(2,4)$ is not equal to the point $(4,2)$.